# undefined reference error for linking CUDA static or shared library with gcc

Tags: c, cuda, shared-libraries, undefined-reference, nvcc

### gcc and CUDA question

Hi,

I have compiled a CUDA shared library but can't link it with the main program that uses it. I am compiling the main program with gcc.

The code:

simplemain.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>



    void fcudadriver();

    int main()
    {
      printf("Main \n");
      fcudadriver();
      return 0;
    }
```

test.cu

```
    __global__ void fcuda()
    {
    }

    void fcudadriver()
    {
      fcuda<<<1,1>>>();
    }
```

I compile test.cu as --> It works

```
    nvcc --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o libtest.so --shared test.cu
```

I compile simplemain.c as ---> It gives error :(

```
    gcc simplemain.c -L. -ltest
    /tmp/ccHnB4Vh.o:simplemain.c:function main: error: undefined reference to 'fcudadriver'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: +1 for including a complete, compilable, simple example

Comment: Bibrak: Please mark @RobertCrovella's answer as accepted if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using g++ instead of gcc.  nvcc uses c++ style linking conventions. (You don't need to rename any files.)

alternatively, if you must use gcc, preface your `void fcudadriver()` function definition like this:

```
extern "C" void fcudadriver()
```

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ name the functions in different way.

Since nvcc treat the CPU code in .cu file as C++, you could rename your `simplemain.c` to `simplemain.cpp`, and compile it with `g++`

Another solution could be adding `extern "C"` before the function definition in the .cu file.